# How to load a page in javascript, so it behaves like a link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have a link refresh the current page using javascript. Currently the page is loaded in a new tab. If the links href is defined the current page is refreshed, how do I duplicate this behaviour in javascript?

Here is the link way which goes to the page requested, page is loaded in current window

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/pageA.php?a=1" > Page A </a>
```

Here is the link and javascript which causes a new tab to be loaded:

```
<script>
function goToPage(url){
    //alert(url);  //displays the correct url
    //window.location= url; // does nothing, it should refresh the page?!?!?!
    window.open(url);   // reloads the  page in a new tab
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick='javascript:goToPage("http://www.mysite.com/pageA.php")' > Page A </a>
```

I have attempted this from numerous methods but nothing seemed to work thus far.

EDIT:
As per the solution below, the onclick call was missing the return false. This is what was causing the page to not be able to load in the current window using the window.location = url.

```
<a href="#" onclick='javascript:goToPage("http://www.mysite.com/pageA.php"); return false;' > Page A </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reload (or load something else) only a portion of page with javascript you need to use ajax.

See this for exampe :
http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-post/

EDIT :
First of all in your scenario 2 things appened :
1) You go to the anchor # (why is the top of your page) because there is no return false in your onclick
2) you open a new page with window.open

Maybe your problem is just the first step ? try :

```
onclick='javascript:goToPage("http://www.mysite.com/pageA.php"); return false'
```

In that case nothing else than page popup will happen.

Comment: Yeah I have been reading some stuff.. but that doesn't answer my question as to why in the above scenario i get only a portion of the page loaded vs the whole page blinks? Is the <a> element using ajax when the href is defined? I know this is simple but I'm feeling a little dumbfounded at the moment.

Comment: The link I am pushing is actually a sidebar menu. So it's annoying when the whole sidebar blinks

Comment: First of all in your scenario 2 things appened :
1) You go to the anchor # (why is the top of your page) because there is no return false in your onclick
2) you open a new page with window.open

Maybe your problem is just the first step ? try :

    onclick='javascript:goToPage("http://www.mysite.com/pageA.php"); return false'
 
In that case nothing else than page popup will happen.

Comment: I just noted that its a new page loading so I made the edits above. The scenario has been corrected.

Comment: so it was the omission of the return false. I was trying forever to get the window.location to work. Thanks for the edit. I actually tried to have the function return false, but that didn't help either.